# Matplotlib plt.plot_date() how to set color for dots based on a third column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My data looks like this:

```
      time             distance color
1   2017-10-10 14:04:14 0.006   yellow
2   2017-10-10 14:04:15 0.011   green
3   2017-10-10 14:04:46 0.051   green
4   2017-10-10 14:04:56 0.063   red
5   2017-10-10 14:05:06 0.073   red
6   2017-10-10 14:05:16 0.081   green
7   2017-10-10 14:05:26 0.095   green
8   2017-10-10 14:05:36 0.103   green
9   2017-10-10 14:05:46 0.113   green
10  2017-10-10 14:05:56 0.124   green
11  2017-10-10 14:06:06 0.134   green
12  2017-10-10 14:06:16 0.149   yellow
13  2017-10-10 14:06:26 0.158   yellow
```

My code is like this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.plot_date(df['time'], df['distance'], marker='o',color='red')    
ax1.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel('distance', color=color, fontsize=20)   
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0,top=80)
ax1.set_xlim(left=xmin, right=xmax) # I set the boundary for x-axis
```

[image]

I would like to assign different colors for each dots based on the column `df['color']`. If I change the code into, it gives error.

```
ax1.plot_date(df['time'], df['distance'], marker='o',color=df['color'])
```

error:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0      yellow
1       yellow
2       green
3       green
4       red
5       red
6       green
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone who knows how to set color for differernt categories labels using a third column for `plt.plot_date()`.

**Note:** I use `plt.plot_date()` rather than `plt.scatter()` because it allows me to choose the timeframe to display on a specific figure and set timeTickers more easily.

Comment: scatter should work much better here, so maybe you want to ask about the problem of using scatter instead?

Comment: Is this a bug in `plot_date()`? It states that it uses the standard matplotlib colors api, but I tested with list of named colors, single letter codes, and passed column series, and all refused to use anything other than a single passed color without using the fix in the accepted answer.

Comment: @G.Anderson No this is not a bug. `plot_date` is the same as `plot` and it accepts a single color specification (although you may have a different markerfacecolor or markeredgecolor). In contrast, `scatter` accepts a list or array of colors - hence my suggestion to use `scatter` instead of `plot` here.

Comment: Aha, yes. I...am not having a good brain day. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` and plot them separately for each color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
color = 'tab:red'
for pcolor, gp in df.groupby('color'):
    ax1.plot_date(gp['time'], gp['distance'], marker='o', color=pcolor) 
...
```

Comment: Wow, this is smart. Thanks a lot! @ALollz

Comment: Well it's simple, not the 'smartest` answer out there. But if you only have a few groups then I'm a fan of simplicity. As Ernest points out, this might be a band-aid fix for an underlying problem that may be better to solve with `scatter`.